# Paperclip, copy image without reprocessing it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

When I copy a paperclip attachment it applies the default cropping defined in the style and ignores the cropper I have installed for cropping on the site via user input (CropperJs). What I need is just a raw copy of the image as it was cropped on the source image. I solve this by bluntly copying the file right now, but is there a better way?

```
has_attached_file :avatar,
    :name => 'avatar',
    :styles => {
      :cropped => {
        :geometry => "55x55#", 
        :processors => [:cropper]
      },
      :large => "600x600>"
}
```